# How to push system metric from one machine to another in linux using collectd?

Tags: linux, bash, collectd

I have two centos Machine, Machine A and Machine B. In machine A i have installed collectd and influxdb. So, the system metric from machine A is pushed into influxdb using collectd. I have installed collectd in machine B. Now, I need to push the system metric from machine B to the influxdb which is in machine A.

Collectd uses the port 25826. When I run the below mentioned command in Machine A my output is:

**Machine A:**

```
command: netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
 output : udp6       0      0 :::25826  :::* 981  325073833  23132/influxd
```

**In Machine B:**

```
sudo netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
```

No output came.

When i use below mentioned command in **Machine B**:

```
command:telnet "xxx.xx.xx.xx" "25826"
output:Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xx: No route to host
```

How to create the host in machine B...So that i can push the metric from Machine B to Machine A...From both machine PING command is working

When i run

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
```

Output:

```
80/tcp 5666/tcp 25826/tcp 25826/udp 3000/tcp
```

Port is added to iptables...eventhough why telnet command is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with iptables firewall rules and allow the ports with the following rules.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25826 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Open a port in IPtables – CentOS 7

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=25826/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Give this a try and post back with the errors you have identified and we shall try to resolve it.

Comment: @Kenlukas thank u so much for replying...Am checking...If i get error i will post ...

Comment: @Kenlukas am sorry,,,I tried your command but getting the same output 
Wheni run the command sudo netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
command:telnet "xxx.xx.xx.xx" "25826"
output:Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xx: No route to host

Pls help me

Comment: @Kenlukas `Ports` are added to iptables...why am not able to push metric into influxdb

Comment: @Kenlukas I added the 25826 in IPtables...but the port is not listenng...Pls help me

Comment: @adiyajoshi, I edited the response, I did not create it.  Aiden supplied the answer.  I would suggest posting an edit to your question showing what you've tried and the error message you're receiving

Comment: @Kenlukas Thank you for helping me....I added the port in the iptables...And now its working...